# Routing pages into components: React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 3 components: `Header.js`, `Main.js`, and `Footer.js`, and `App.js` is like

```
const App = () => {
   <Header/>
   <Main/>
   <Footer/>
}
```

In the `Header.js` I have links like `About` and `Projects`. I would like to be able when I click `About` in the header for example to display the page `About.js` in `Main.js`, and when I click `Projects` to display the page `Projects.js` in the `Main.js` component. I tried to use Routing in the `Main.js` component like

```
const Main = () => {
   <Router>
     <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' component={About.js} />
         <Route exact path='/projects' component={Projects.js} />
     </Switch>
   </Router>
}
```

but it wouldn't allow me, saying that I cannot use `Link` outside a router, where I use `Link` in the `Header.js`. How can I achieve this?

The `Header.js` is the following

```
const Header = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">
            About
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/projects">
            Projects
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Are you using react-router? If so, where’s your `Router` component?

Comment: See updated question, please

Comment: You should just be able to pull your Router component up to the App level and make sure it surrounds both your header and main.

Comment: But in that case, the selected page won't appear in the space where I want it to appear in. Basically, the Header and Footer are constant, but the Main changes. This is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to make sure your `Router` component surrounds any components doing routing. For simplicity, here’s the router surrounding your whole app at the App level.

```
const App = () => {
  <Router>
    <Header/>
    <Main/>
    <Footer/>
  </Router>
}
```

Edit: make sure you’re passing your components correctly to the Routes:

```
const Main = () => {
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={About} />
    <Route exact path='/projects' component={Projects} />
 </Switch>
}
```

Comment: OK, what about the `Switch` and `Route`. Can I keep them in `Main.js`?

Comment: Yeah. That should be fine. The router component doesn’t dictate where the routes render, that’s what the Route components are for

Comment: Tried it but didn't achieve what I want. Nothing appears in the `Main.js` component!!

Comment: Oh, I think you just want to say About or Projects in the component prop. Make sure you’re importing them correctly. About.js and Project.js aren’t right

Comment: Yes, basically I want to include `About.js` and `Projects.js` as `{props.children}` in `Main.js`, but I am not sure how to switch between them when I click the corresponding `Link` in the header. Do I need to use global state for this?

Comment: @BlackMath no, just make sure you’re passing the component correctly to each Route. See my edited answer

Comment: OK. Now it's working. I was adding the extension `.js` in the `component` property of the the `Route`. That was my mistake. Thanks a lot

Comment: @BlackMath no problem